# PostgreSQL get time difference between two text fields

Tags: postgresql

I have two fields in table like

```
Time1(varchar)     Time2(varchar)
13:01:15           14:02:06
```

How do I get the time difference between these two fields?

Comment: The real question is: why are you storing a time value in a `varchar`  column. That should be stored in a column with the type `time`

Comment: Actually it is developed by some other team.

Comment: I am using  their database for just generating reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the values to a proper time value, then simply subtract them:

```
'14:02:06'::time - '13:01:15'::time
```

or

```
time_2::time - time_1::time
```

The result is an [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

Comment: We're assuming that time_2 is always greater than time_1 here. It might be worth updating the query to `greatest(time_1::time, time_2::time) - least(time_1::time, time_2::time)`

Comment: @Scoots: an interval can be negative

Comment: can I use sum(time_2::time - time_1::time) in a group by query.

Comment: I think it should work, if (time_2::time - time_1::time ) output is of type interval

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As OP wants to sum them, a mixture of positive and negative intervals will be detrimental. Admittedly both our comments come before we knew that though.